# playing video on top of OpenGL view in android

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game using cocos2d-x and I want to play video in it.
The activity has one OpenGL view and I also put additional VideoView on top of it and set visibility to INVISIBLE.

When I need to play video, I just hide OpenGL view and enable my VideoView. After that I create MediaPlayer, call setDisplay with holder of that VideoView, etc. and eventually video plays well. When video finishes, I switch visibilities back again - opengl to VISIBLE and videoview to INVISIBLE.

However, the problem is that when I try to play video second time, it just doesn't show up, however, sound from the video is being played.

Is there any catch with visibilities?

Answer (score 3):

I just modified the ApiDemo to see whether it works. I have blog the full code here : [post](http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.sg/2012/06/android-play-video-on-top-of.html) without using separate media player for video view we can set the video and play

```
   mVideoView.setVideoURI(data.getData());
   mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mVideoView.start();

   //I could add touch listener in onCreate
    mGLSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(...);

//touch event will go all the way down to GLSurfaceView
//Here i could chnage the video view position
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    mVideoView.setTranslationX(motionEvent.getX());
    mVideoView.setTranslationY(motionEvent.getY());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since this is creating a view on top of the OpenGL View, while it is invisible will I be able to touch 'through' it? In other words, will this layer allow touches to pass through it to the OpenGL layer?

Comment: I could listen for motion event by setting the touch listener, I have updated the post with those changes too

Answer (score 1):

You will need a surfaceview to play video at using android MediaPlayer class.

To play video above GLSurfaceView, create an android Custom Dialog which contains a surfaceView and play video on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding dynamically video view on the surface of glview. First create a parent view (any layout) add video view in same parent view then add this parent view on the gl surface view. I have done this before and it was working for me. for your reference :

```
     // first set the content view as your glview with your params.
     setContentView(mGLView, gl_params);
     mGLView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);

     // add a parent view for video view. rl is relative layout
     addContentView(rl, rl_params);

     // now add the video view inside this parent view.
     rl.addview(video_view, video_view_params)
```